# How to format the font of a Unicode character in SCSS

Tags: css, sass

I'm stuck on a CSS issue, we have the following class:

```
.OnSwitch {
    &:after { 
      content: "";
      z-index: 1;
      top: 18px;
      right: 15px;
      position: absolute;
      font-size: 16px;
    }
    &.tempControlled:after {
      content: "\2109";
    }
    &.weightControlled:after {
      content: "LBS";
    }
  }
```

in the content element we're using the \2109 to display the Farenheit character.  It's showing up fine, however it's a serif font and we need a sans serif font to fit with the rest of the page.  I've tried adding font-family to both the tempControlled:after and the parent class but no luck.

Comment: Maybe the font doesn't include that character, or maybe the font isn't loaded correctly, or maybe the font is overridden by another style?

Comment: I'd use the dev-tools in your browser to inspect the element because that unicode character _**is**_ a sans-serif character. I'm really interested to know how it's being displayed as serif style

Comment: Consider using: `content: " \000B0 F";` this way at least the character `F` can be styled with css

Answer (score 0):

I live in Celsius world and had to google the Fahrenheit character ℉ https://www.htmlsymbols.xyz/unicode/U+2109 displays it in sans-serif; they are using (adapted to your code)

```css
&.tempControlled:after {
    content: "\2109";
    font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol";
}
```

This is a pretty common stack these days and requires no additional `@font-face` if you drop Roboto. To my taste this would be one of the rare cases that even justifies to add `!important` if needed.

I hope this helps!